# Selenium 3.8 + Firefox 56/57 não roda em Background

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Tenho um serviço atualmente que roda com Firefox 46 + Selenium 2.53. Porem estou precisando atualiza-lo e estou tentando utilizar o Firefox 56 ou 57 com Selenium 3.8. Quando executo na minha máquina o serviço roda bonito, porém quando vou rodá-lo como windows service, não funciona e tomo este erro "Process unexpectedly closed with status: 0"

```
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            profile.SetPreference("dom.ipc.plugins.enabled", false);
            profile.SetPreference("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Services\\RoboLEDBBService\\geckodriver.exe");

            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.Profile = profile;

            try
            {

                driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {}
```

Comment: Provavelmente é devido a novas mudanças do Firefox quantum, talvez não tenham implementado, verifica se você esta realmente usando a ultima versão do geckodriver (creio que a ultima seja o 0.19.1). Houve uma atualização no Selenium a alguns dias https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/576feaf5b1e3cbe1dbd27dfa201273454f93f7ea, não sei se tem haver com o problema, mas foi um update pra firefox